# How to pass Expression<Func<T, bool>> to a method

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I have caller method:

```
public async Task<bool> HasAnyPolicyByName(string name, int[] clientsIds, CancellationToken token = default)
{
    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = .Where(x => clientsIds.Contains(x.ClientId) && x.Name == name);
    var policyDetails = await _context.AutomaticHourPolicies.GetItemsAsync(predicate);
}
```

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetItemsAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, CancellationToken token = default)
{
    IDocumentQuery<T> query = _dbClient.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(_collectionUri, new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1 }).Where(predicate).AsDocumentQuery();
    List<T> results = new List<T>();
    //... removed code for simplicity
    return results;
}
```

How to pass predicate input object for second method?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking here. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Predicate is `x => clientsIds.Contains(x.ClientId) && x.Name == name`, not `.Where(x => clientsIds.Contains(x.ClientId) && x.Name == name)`

Comment: I want to pass expression query to my method, but I dont know how to pass it? variable predicate int he first method should be passed to a method `GetItemsAsync`
But Im not sure how?

Comment: Is `GetItemsAsync` supposed to be some extension method (otherwise `_context.AutomaticHourPolicies.GetItemsAsync` looks suspicious taking in account provided `GetItemsAsync` signature)? Can you please add a [mre]?

Answer (score 2):

By your example, the code need to be changed to

```
public async Task<bool> HasAnyPolicyByName(string name, int[] clientsIds, CancellationToken token = default)
{
    var policyDetails = await _context.AutomaticHourPolicies.GetItemsAsync(x => clientsIds.Contains(x.ClientId) && x.Name == name);
    //...
}
```

As @Guru Stron mentioned `x => clientsIds.Contains(x.ClientId) && x.Name == name` is the predicate need to be passed.

Comment: Upvoted. Apparently, `AutomaticHourPolicies` has the `T` in scope, so you do not have to explicitly say what `T` is (the called method `GetItemsAsync` appears nongeneric and it uses some `T` from its containing class).